# How to set the height of button in React Native Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am learning React Native programming for Android mobile apps. I am making a screen where I need to set height of `button.` I have added `button` in `view` and set the height of using style however there is no change on button height.

```
/**
 * LoginComponent of Myntra
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from "react-native";

class LoginComponent extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", margin: 10 }}>
            <TextInput
                style={{
                    height: 40,
                    borderColor: "gray",
                    borderWidth: 0.5
                }}
                placeholder="Email address"
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            />

            <TextInput
                style={{
                    height: 40,
                    borderColor: "gray",
                    borderWidth: 0.5
                }}
                placeholder="Password"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            />

            <View style={{ height: 100, marginTop: 10 }}>
                <Button title="LOG IN" color="#2E8B57" />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("Myntra", () => LoginComponent);
```

Can anyone help me to set the height of button according to my requirement?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This component has limited options, so you can't resize it to a fixed `height`.

I recommend you to use the `TouchableOpacity` component to build your own button, with own `properties` and `styles`.

You can easily style it like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 100, marginTop: 10 }}>
    <Text>My button</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Jesus Christ!!! I just started using React Native and already hate it lol So many limitations for styles.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the button width as per the mentioned width easily by using following method :

```
<View style={[{ width: "90%", margin: 10, backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="Button Three"
            color="#FF3D00"
          />
        </View>
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, but the OP was asking specifically about setting the height

Comment: For that,  we need to use height attribute of css design.

Comment: The reason for using the TouchableOpacity component is because you can't change the Button components height unfortunately.

Comment: we can change the button width and height by using below line of code :  
     `<View style={[{ width: "50%",  height: "50%",margin: 10, backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="Button Three"
            color="#FF3D00"
          />
        </View>`

Comment: To @sumitkumarpradhan, I have tested: width works, but height does not work. At least when style={{flex:1}} is set. Setting height from 0% to 100% ends up with a button of the same height.

Comment: try this : <View style={[{ width: "50%", height: "50%",margin: 10, backgroundColor: "red" }]}> <Button onPress={this.buttonClickListener} title="Button Three" color="#FF3D00" /> </View>

Comment: Styling the parent box instead will result in a poor UX, because it creates an area which will not respond to clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to use minHeight or maxHeight instead of using Height const.

Answer (score 1):

It often happens that we want to change the dimensions of the button, which by default is extended to the entire width of the parent element. While reducing its width is not a problem – it is enough to reduce the width of the parent, but changing the height is already problematic. The Button element has no style property, so apart from changing the text color on iOS and the background color on Android, we can not set much in it.

To have more control over the button, it is better to use TouchableOpacity or TouchableNativeFeedback instead.

TouchableOpacity Function Component Example -

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const onPress = () => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.countContainer}>
        <Text>Count: {count}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={onPress}
      >
        <Text>Press Here</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
    padding: 10
  },
  countContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 10
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The component **Button** supports a minimal level of customization, so you have to use an other component.

You can use : [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) or [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity) ,

```
<Pressable onPress={onPressFunction} style={styles.yourButtonStyle}>
    <Text>I'm pressable!</Text>
</Pressable

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  yourButtonStyle: {
   ...
  }
});
```

[Doc Button](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<View style={styles.btnContainer}>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <Button style={styles.btnSize}>
      <Text>Change Address</Text>
    </Button>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <Button style={styles.btnSize}>
      <Text>Change Address</Text>
    </Button>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

**Style sheet code snippet**

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    btnContainer:{
        flexDirection:"row",
        justifyContent:"space-between"
    },
    btnSize:{
        width:"100%"
    }
})
```

Comment: This code will throw an error. Also, a Button element inside a TouchableOpacity element makes zero sense. Keep the TouchableOpacity or put the Button in a generic View to add a style object.